# CSS e JS não carrega no celular, via localhost

Tags: php, bootstrap-3, xampp, codeigniter-3

Bom dia! Estou fazendo um pequeno site, usando *Codeigniter 3* e *Bootstrap 3*.

No PC, o CSS e JS funcionam perfeitamente bem, mas quando tento acessá-lo pelo *Smartphone*, pelo localhost, carrega **somente** o HTML.

**Observação**: Estou usando o XAMPP.

O que pode ser?

*Exemplo de Chamada de CSS:

```
 <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/site.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

*Exemplo de chamada de JS:

```
 <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/site.js'); ?>"></script>
```

*Base URL está configurada dessa maneira:

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/teste';
```

*No PC, digito a URL: **localhost/teste.** - Funciona normalmente.

*No smartphone eu digito o endereço IP no lugar de "localhost": EX.: **192.168.x.x/teste**. - Não carrega CSS, nem JS. Só o HTML.

Comment: Favor, incrementar sua pergunta com códigos, chamadas do CSS, assim podemos ajudá-lo melhor

Comment: A pergunta foi editada. Adicionei código.

Comment: cara, sua constante base_url tem que pegar automaticamente a url, não setar manualmente

Comment: tem um código completão ali em baixo, mas pode utilizar este também define('BASE_URL', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
echo BASE_URL

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas infelizmente não deu certo. Baseado nas respostas de vocês, encontrei uma resposta satisfatória na internet, que resolveu meu problema. Link: http://www.universidadecodeigniter.com.br/otimizando-a-configuracao-da-url-base-da-aplicacao/

Comment: $base_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base_url;

Answer (score 1):

utilize isso para criar a variável de base_url ou constante

```
<?php
    define('siteprot', $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://');
    define('sitehost', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    define('siteuri',  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    define('siteindex', '/'.max(explode('/', dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))).'/');
    define('siteurl', siteprot . sitehost . siteindex);
?>

<li>
    <?php echo siteurl; ?>
</li>
<li>
    <?php echo siteprot; ?>
</li>
<li>
    <?php echo sitehost; ?>
</li>
<li>
    <?php echo siteuri; ?>
</li>
<li>
    <?php echo siteindex; ?>
</li>
```

Desculpe, o código postado foi um beta, só agora vi, realmente tem defeito de digitação, o código final seria este acima, o mesmo pode ser visto funcionando [aqui neste link](http://dkteclive.com/plugins/php/autoloadurl.php), ele detecta todos os parâmetros como HTTP ou HTTPS e também o subdir para poder criar url amigável

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas infelizmente não deu certo. Baseado nas respostas de vocês, encontrei uma resposta satisfatória na internet, que resolveu meu problema. Link: http://www.universidadecodeigniter.com.br/otimizando-a-configuracao-da-url-base-da-aplicacao/

Comment: $base_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base_url;

Comment: que bom que achou a solução, mas de uma estudada nesta solução acima, é mais robusta, também já utilizei esta que você informou a muitos anos atrás, fui a melhorando até que cheguei nesta que lhe enviei que é coletânea automática do início ao fim, utilizar url amigável é a melhor solução